# カスタムタクソノミーにAdvanced Custom Fieldsで設定したタームを出力させたい。

Tags: wordpress

カスタム投稿タイプに、makerというカスタムタクソノミーを設定し、makerそれぞれの一覧ページに、そのmakerの説明等の情報を表示させたく思います。

「makerの説明等の情報」は、Advanced Custom Fieldsで設定し、情報を入力しましたが、
Advanced Custom Fieldsで設定したタームの出力方法がわからないです。

いろいろ調べてもわからず、、
どなたか、ご存知でしたらご教授願います。

### 補足

maker→取引先会社
makerそれぞれの一覧ページ→各取引会社

### 環境

wordpress 5.4

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。

カスタムタクソノミー内で、カスタムフィールドを出力させるためには、下記のやり方でokです。

下記2項目を、あなたが設定したものに変更すれば問題なく出力できます。

・カスタムタクソノミーの名前 × 3
・カスタムフィールド　×　1

```
<?php
$term_slug = get_query_var('カスタムタクソノミーの名前');
$term_ID = get_term_by('slug',$term_slug,'カスタムタクソノミーの名前')->term_id;
$hoge = the_field( 'カスタムタクソノミーに追加したカスタムフィールドの名前', 'カスタムタクソノミーの名前_'.$term_ID);
?>
```

引用元
https://fukudon.com/advanced-custom-fields/